# PHP For loop, how to loop code after 6 rows are displayed

Tags: php, database, for-loop

So I am trying to wrap a div around my database results. The div must appear before first row and after the 6th row, it needs to close the div and loop it again. I tried to do it, but I can't manage to make it work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++) {
 if (($i) % 6 == 0) {
 echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
 }
 echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
 <img src="images/preview.jpg">
 </div>';
 if (($i) % 6 == 0) {
 echo '</div>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also the code sample was not working at all (for/if/else not closed), see if this helps:

```
echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';

for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++)
{
  if (($i>0) && ($i%6==0)) {
    echo '</div>'."\n".'<div class="swiper-slide">';
  }

  echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><img src="images/preview.jpg"></div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

[test at eval.in](https://eval.in/189679)

Comment: Many thanks, your code worked perfectly fine. Even thought @Yazan code was working, but it displayed wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="swiper-slide"><!-- open it using HTML out of <??> php tags-->

<?php
for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++) {

    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><img src="images/preview.jpg"></div>';

    if ($i % 6 == 0) {
        //close and open new div for each group of 6
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    }//every 6th ... (you may need to change itto ( $i % 5 == 0)

}//for loop
echo '</div>';//close last opened, in case no more data or data less that 6
?>
```

Comment: If `$i % 6 === 0` on the last iteration this would create an empty `.swiper-slide` div.

Answer (score 0):

Your second modulo operator compares the result to 9 instead of 0, and you have a `}` missing:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($row); $i++) {
    if (($i) % 6 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><img src="images/preview.jpg"></div>';
    if (($i) % 6 == 0) { // Corrected 9 to 0
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a typo, don't know how I missed it. Oh do I? Will check it now.

Comment: @darko to avoid syntax and typos it's in better preference to use a ide, eclipse of phpstorm get my vote

Comment: @DarylGill thanks for the tip, thought I use Brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($row as $key=>$result) {
    if ($key==0 || $key == 5) { //If this is the first or sixth row.
      echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    }
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"><img src="images/preview.jpg"></div>';

    if ($key==0 || $key == 5) { 
      echo '</div>';
    }
}
```